# Problem with a probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $\Omega=\{w_{1},\dots,w_{n}\}$ and define a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ with the condition that the probability of $w_{j+1}$ is the double of the probability of $w_{j}$. Let $A_{k}=\{w_{1},\dots,w_{k}\}$. Compute $\mathbb{P}(A_{k})$.

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Can you work out the probability of each $\omega_j$ in terms of the probability of $\omega_1$? What must they sum to?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen : In view of the answers below, it seems that there was no part of this problem that Eduardo was left to do on his own. Does this help Eduardo, or insult his intelligence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1\\=\mathbb{P}(\Omega)\\=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n\})\\=\mathbb{P}(\cup_{i=1}^n\{\omega_i\})\\=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(\{\omega_i\})\\=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(\{\omega_1\})\cdot 2^{i-1}\\=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega_1\})\sum_{i=1}^n2^{i-1}\\=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega_1\})\cdot (2^n-1)$

Thus $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega_1\})=\frac{1}{2^n-1}.$ Now use induction and the fact that $\omega_{j+1}$ has double the probability of $\omega_{j}$, then compute $\mathbb{P}(A_k)$.

Comment: This seems like a little more than just a hint : ). Mind that the sum of powers of two should certainly not be $2^n$ (eg $1 + 2 \ne 2^2$), unless perhaps this is a crafty way to teach OP by misleading him

Comment: Okay Izaak, fixed typo.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use the normalization axiom of your probability rule in conjunction with the given recursive definition. To do this, set the first value, $w_0$ equal to a constant, $k$, then each successive probability is given by $\mathbb{P}(w_1)=2C$, $\mathbb{P}(w_2)=4C$ and so on following $\mathbb{P}(w_i)=2^iC$. We know the total probability has to be one to have a valid probability rule, so if we sum over all the events, we should get one.

Thus, $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}2^{i+1}k = 1$

Using the formula for a finite geometric series,
$1=C2(\frac{1-2^{N}}{1-2})$, $C=\frac{1-2}{2-2^{N+1}}$.

So for $\mathbb{P}(w_k)=2^kC=2^k(\frac{1-2}{2-2^{N+1}})$